# c# Bluetooth Mac Address of our Adapter

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, 32feet

I am using IntheHand 32feet library http://32feet.codeplex.com/
I am searching for a code to get local MAC Address of Bluetooth Adapter . I have tried may quick tweaks but not worked like

```
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
```

and

```
          BluetoothListener btListener;
btListener.Server.AddressFamily.ToString();
```

but doesn't work. Please suggest the way I can get the address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Local%20Radio%20Information

```
BluetoothRadio myRadio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
if (myRadio == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("No radio hardware or unsupported software stack");
    return;
}
RadioMode mode = myRadio.Mode;
// Warning: LocalAddress is null if the radio is powered-off.
Console.WriteLine("* Radio, address: {0:C}", myRadio.LocalAddress);
```